# Reverse dns returns a different host each time

Tags: ping, reverse-dns

So, randomly I happened to ping abc.com and found this fascinating:

```
$ ping abc.com
PING abc.com (199.181.132.250) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from m.abc.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=1 ttl=237 time=90.3 ms
64 bytes from tdl.disneyuniversity.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=2 ttl=237 time=89.8 ms
64 bytes from preschooltime.go.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=3 ttl=237 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from futbolpicante.espnfc.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=4 ttl=237 time=98.6 ms
64 bytes from www.worldofcars.go.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=5 ttl=237 time=86.9 ms
64 bytes from www.verizon.bravesweepstakes.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=6 ttl=237 time=87.9 ms
64 bytes from www.directv.bravesweepstakes.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=7 ttl=237 time=87.9 ms
64 bytes from manup.abc.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=8 ttl=237 time=88.8 ms
64 bytes from m.onemoredisneyday.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=9 ttl=237 time=87.5 ms
64 bytes from finance.abc30.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=10 ttl=237 time=87.9 ms
64 bytes from finance.abc13.com (199.181.132.250): icmp_req=11 ttl=237 time=88.0 ms
...
```

In a way it seems similar to load balancing used in forward DNS, except I don't understand how this would be useful.

Is there any practical reason for this or just a consequence of these sites all being hosted behind the same IP address?

Comment: Isn't that forward DNS?  Reverse would be if you searched by IP.  It doesn't happen when I ping them now.  I get the same result repeatedly.  Perhaps this has something to do with the way their DNS wildcard works?

Answer (score 1):

nslookup 199.181.132.250 shows up witn bunch of non-authoritative answers for different domain names. But my ping doesn't change dynamically as yours.

Answer (score 1):

It really looks someone just being funny, or server misconfigured or something like that. There are actually that many reverse records.

btw. i suspect this IP might be used to distribute spam and these hostnames are there to confuse filters. (but that is a wild guess)

see:

```
$ dig 250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa -t PTR
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> 250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa -t PTR
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33536
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 195, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa.  IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.nightofjoy.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.disneyworld.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.mustdodisney.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.disneytheforce.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.onemoredisneyday.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     s.espnradio.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     fb.steelgetsreal.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     my.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     qa.watchdisneyxd.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     qa.watchabcfamily.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     qa.watchdisneyjunior.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     qa.watchdisneychannel.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     uk.disneycareers.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     abc.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     cdn.musiclounge.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     fdj.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     fdj.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     gma.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hdf.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hub.disneyuniversity.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     itm.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     lnb.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     sam.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     tdl.disneyuniversity.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     ugc.lionking.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     ugc.marypoppins.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     ugv.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     vpd.disneycruise.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     w88.m.fwfest.waltdisneyworld.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.att.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.cox.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.ttdl.disneyuniversity.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.enter.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.charter.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.directv.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.verizon.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.mediacom.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.adventure.bravesweepstakes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneyhome.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.worldofcars.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneycasting.net.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.donovandecker.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneyroommate.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneycampusrep.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneycollateral.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneyinternsinfo.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.missiontimekeeper.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneycastingscout.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneyimaginations.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneyprogramsblog.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.wdwcollegeprogramecard.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.wdwcollegeprogramecard2.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     www.disneyinternationalepresentation.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     1ext.doit.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     25th.disneystore.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     beta.xgames.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     blog.disneyxd.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     bmoc.abc7chicago.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     doit.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     live.dadt.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     live.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     play.toontown.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     prod.waltdisneystudios.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     ugv2.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     blogs.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     cards.babyzone.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     email.doit.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     email.disneymovieclub.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     espn3.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     games.soapnet.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     manup.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     panam.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     castle.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     comedy.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     espnrf.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hdfmas.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     health.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     mobile.abcfamily.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     oscars.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     photos.kaboose.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     photos.babyzone.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     search.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     search.video.movies.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     temail.disneymovieclub.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     tienda.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     topics.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     velti2.disneylandsummer.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     workit.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     999test.abcnews.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     account.toontown.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     casting.disneyparks.jobs.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     catalog.disneyuniversity.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     clarity.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     culture.disneyuniversity.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.6abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.abc7.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.abc11.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.abc13.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.abc30.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.7online.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.abc7news.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     finance.abc7chicago.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hotseat.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     missing.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     playdom.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     preview.mydisneyphotopass.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     revenge.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     scandal.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     scrumtv.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     search2.spanish.disneylandsummer.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     theview.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     topics2.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     uplayit.abc7chicago.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     developu.disneyuniversity.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyhd.tv.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     polo2011.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     theriver.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     whereami.doit.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     abccomedy.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     helpoffer.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     rugby2011.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     shelterme.6abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     stagepass.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     tenis2011.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     themiddle.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     trongames.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     cougartown.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     devicedata.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneytime.disneyparks.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyvisa.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     experience.disneydestinations.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     happyrides.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     portfolios.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     storefront.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     bodyofproof.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     copavirtual.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     desafioeuro.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyparks.jobs.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     familytools.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     glass-house.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hipcricket2.spanish.disneylandsummer.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     klubpenguin.de.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     klubpinguin.de.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     musiclounge.abc.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     preolimpico.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     radiodisney.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     suburgatory.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     weatherblog.abc13.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     abcdotcomedy.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     euroquiniela.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     happyendings.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     modernfamily.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     sendtofriend.abcnews.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     desafiofutmex.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     dimgpressroom.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneypackage.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneystudios.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     futbolpicante.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     golesdeeuropa.espnfc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     onceuponatime.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     preschooltime.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     rincontecnico.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     yourcommunity.6abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     desafiopremier.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     phineasandferb.disneymags.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyparksblog.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyvisaperks.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     elmejorejemplar.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     lastmanstanding.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     monstroussummer.disneyparks.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     the-glass-house.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyconnection.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     avalanchesoftware.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     celebritywifeswap.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyhumanrights.org.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneysecondscreen.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     watchdisneychannel.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hablemosdefutbolmas.espndeportes.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     mickeystrickortreat.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneylearningstudio.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     shanghaidisneyresort.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneystarbuckssurvey.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyworldsvacations.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     wheelchairrentaldisney.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     hyperionbooksforchildren.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     disneyparksstarbuckssurvey.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.abc.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.test.doit.go.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.fwfest.waltdisneyworld.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.abcfamily.com.
250.132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180 IN    PTR     m.bostonmed.abcnews.go.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180   IN      NS      sens01.dig.com.
132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180   IN      NS      orns01.dig.com.
132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180   IN      NS      sens02.dig.com.
132.181.199.in-addr.arpa. 180   IN      NS      orns02.dig.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
orns01.dig.com.         257     IN      A       68.71.223.14
sens02.dig.com.         242     IN      A       199.181.135.199

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 19 23:24:14 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 5471
```

Answer (score 0):

This is used for "forward-confirmed reverse DNS." From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS)

> A FCrDNS verification can create a weak form of authentication that
>   there is a valid relationship between the owner of a domain name and
>   the owner of the network that has been given an IP address. While
>   weak, this authentication is strong enough that it can be used for
>   whitelisting purposes because spammers and phishers can not usually
>   by-pass this verification when they use zombie computers for mail
>   spoofing. That is, the reverse DNS might verify, but it will usually
>   be part of an other domain than the claimed domain name.

However, I know of no application that actually looks at more than 1 PTR RR. It could be that Disney has some services that look at more than 1 PTR RR.